# wordpress смена статуса поста

Tags: wordpress

При попытке сменить статус поста через функцию `wp_update_post` создаётся копию поста.
Как иначе можно просто изменить статус поста?

```
if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
   remove_action('save_post', 'premoderationTA');
   $new_post_status = array(
     'ID' => $post_id,
     'post_status' => 'draft'
    );
    wp_update_post($new_post_status);
    add_action( 'save_post', 'premoderationTA');
}
```

Comment: Не забываете указать id обновляемого поста?

Comment: Разве эту функцию вообще возможно без ID запустить?

Comment: В любом случае было бы здорово, если бы вы показали свой код

Comment: Добавил к посту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается `post_id` действительно была пустая. При использовании функции `get_the_ID` всё стало корректно работать